# Problematic Behavior of Graphics.FillPath()

Tags: c#, gdi+

I created a small function that draws a Rectangle with finer edges.
(you can call it a rounded rectangle)

Here is how I do it:

```
private void    DrawRoundedRectangle(Graphics G, int X1, int Y1, int X2, int Y2)
{
    GraphicsPath    GP  =new GraphicsPath();
    GP.AddLine(X1+1,Y1  ,  X2-1,Y1  );
    GP.AddLine(X2-1,Y1  ,  X2  ,Y1+1);
    GP.AddLine(X2  ,Y1+1,  X2  ,Y2-1);
    GP.AddLine(X2  ,Y2-1,  X2-1,Y2  );
    GP.AddLine(X2-1,Y2  ,  X1+1,Y2  );
    GP.AddLine(X1+1,Y2  ,  X1  ,Y2-1);
    GP.AddLine(X1  ,Y2-1,  X1  ,Y1+1);
    GP.AddLine(X1  ,Y1+1,  X1+1,Y1  );

    G.DrawPath(Pens.Blue,GP);
}
```

And here is the Paint event handler that calls this function:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    this.DrawRoundedRectangle(e.Graphics,50,50,60,55);
}
```

Running it, indeed gives the desired result, which is this:

[image]

A good result as I wished.

However If I change the
`G.DrawPath(Pens.Blue,GP);`
line to be:
`G.FillPath(Brushes.Blue,GP);`
then what I get is this:

[image]

Not the result I wanted..
The bottom part of the rectangle is sharp, and not rounded as needed,  like it was with the DrawPath() method.

Anyone knows what I should do to make the FillPath() method work well too?
If It matters, I am using .NET Framework 2.0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oddly drawn GraphicsPath with Graphics.FillPath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167463/oddly-drawn-graphicspath-with-graphics-fillpath)

Comment: Hi blas3nik. The problem in the other question is indeed similar to here, yet I don't see how the workaround that is given there can help here, with a small shape like this.. If anyone does understand the workaround there and how to use it here too, please write.. Thank you

Comment: Looks like the GraphicsPath got the old Fill- vs DrawRectanlge bug the other way round. Since you can't make the brush fill on the inside it is either modify the coordinates as in the link /and why would it not work with small sizes; it is only 1 pixel after all) or go for FillPolygon instead.. (it that gets it right../?)

Comment: GDI+ uses floating point math internally, troubleshooting the off-by-one errors produced by having to round to integral pixels is *very* little fun.  You invariably get somewhat ahead by setting the Graphics.PixelOffsetMode to Half, the default is only a good choice for rendering bitmaps.  That affects your shape pretty noticeably, getting it pixel-perfect is still an elusive goal.  GDI+ was designed 15+ years ago with the assumption that resolution-independent graphics would soon be a practical reality.  That it still is not is a fair tragedy.

Comment: TaW: Regarding FillPolygon(), I checked now and unfortunately it doesn't give any different result.. Regarding "why would it not work with small sizes; it is only 1 pixel after all)" - I don't understand what to change in my code to try what they did there.

Comment: Hans Passant: Thank you very much, it's interesting and definitely makes sense now. floating point math has a tendency to "move" a little bit from the accurate value.. BTW, I heard that in WPF this problem does not exist.. But I haven't tried it yet

Comment: Same problem in WPF, less because it uses *double* instead of *float* and it interpolates more aggressively.  The inconsistent SnapToDevicePixels is very little fun the same way.  It only *really* looks good when you step back at least three feet or spend the money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a *real* rounded-rect implementation, you should use the code in the question referenced by [commenter blas3nik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34224961/problematic-behavior-of-graphics-fillpath#comment56197579_34224961), at [Oddly drawn GraphicsPath with Graphics.FillPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167463/oddly-drawn-graphicspath-with-graphics-fillpath).

Your implementation mainly just removes each of the pixels at the four corners. As such, there's no need to use `GraphicsPath` to draw this. Just fill a couple of overlapping rectangles that exclude those pixels:

```
    private void FillRoundedRectangle(Graphics G, int X1, int Y1, int X2, int Y2)
    {
        int width = X2 - X1, height = Y2 - Y1;

        G.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, X1 + 1, Y1, width - 2, height);
        G.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, X1, Y1 + 1, width, height - 2);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Peter, very nice workaround. Another workaround that I implemented yesterday, is to use DrawPath() to draw the outer GraphicsPath, which does it correctly, and then, to do FillRectangle, for the internal rectangle inside the outer graphicspath.. But I am switching now to your workaround, since it is achieved with less code, and should be faster due to that too.