# Inconsistent behaviour between FillRectangle, DrawRectangle and SetClip in gdi+ Graphics class

Tags: windows, gdi+

First of all I am aware of this post here:
[Pixel behaviour of FillRectangle and DrawRectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147569/pixel-behaviour-of-fillrectangle-and-drawrectangle). But it does not fully address my issue.

Let's start with a square of length 3 created as follows:

```
RectF rc(0, 0, 3, 3);
```

If I fill this rectangle using `Graphics::FillRectangle()` then I get a square of 3 x 3 pixels as seen in the image below with the 2 little white squares:

[image]

If I then try to draw a border around these squares using `Graphics::DrawRectangle()`, and supplying exactly the same rect I used when I filled them, I get a border which covers 4 x 4 pixels thereby visually extending the squares by a pixel on the right and bottom:

[image]

I am led to understand this is because FillRectangle() doesn't draw the right or bottom edge. I can't find any documentation on why it behaves this way.

If I then bring `Graphics::SetClip()` into the equation, and set the clipping region to the same rect I have used in the previous 2 tests I get the following:

[image]

So, now the clipping region seems to ignore the right and bottom edges the same way that `FillRectangle()` does which seems silly given how `DrawRectangle()` works.

Can someone help me understand how all of this inconsistency should be interpreted?

Answer (score 2):

`FillRectangle` and `SetClip` ignore the right and bottom edges because that's the definition of a rectangle in Windows; it's two open ranges where the start points are included but the end points are not. That means you can easily define an *empty* rectangle where top=bottom or left=right. It also means if the top of one rectangle is the bottom of another, the two will meet perfectly with no overlap.

`DrawRectangle` is different, because it's defining a polygon with 4 sides and drawing those sides.