# C# - DrawBorder - Bottom and Right side not visible

Tags: c#

I want to add a different bordercolor for every side of the element,
yet it's working pretty okay, the only problem I got is that my right side and bottom side of the border isn't visible.

```
        public static void DrawBorder
    (
        Graphics graphics, Rectangle bounds,
        Color leftColor, int leftWidth, ButtonBorderStyle leftStyle,
        Color topColor, int topWidth, ButtonBorderStyle topStyle,
        Color rightColor, int rightWidth, ButtonBorderStyle rightStyle,
        Color bottomColor, int bottomWidth, ButtonBorderStyle bottomStyle
    ){}
    Color leftColor = Color.FromArgb(65,0,0,0), rightColor = Color.FromArgb(150, 0, 0, 0), topColor = Color.FromArgb(65, 0, 0, 0), bottomColor = Color.FromArgb(150, 0, 0, 0);
    int leftWidth = 3, rightWidth = 3, topWidth = 3, bottomWidth = 3;
    ButtonBorderStyle leftStyle = ButtonBorderStyle.Solid, rightStyle = ButtonBorderStyle.Solid, topStyle = ButtonBorderStyle.Solid, bottomStyle = ButtonBorderStyle.Solid;

    private void Paint_(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle borderRectangle = this.ClientRectangle;
        borderRectangle.Inflate(0, 0);
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, borderRectangle,
        leftColor, leftWidth, leftStyle,
        topColor, topWidth, topStyle,
        rightColor, rightWidth, rightStyle,
        bottomColor, bottomWidth, bottomStyle);
    }
```

I'm using the "Paint_" function for every element you see here, so it's the same problem on every of these.
[image: Missing right and bottom border]
I'm pretty new to any of the "Draw" stuff, so I don't know anything which could be the problem.

Comment: Pens draw a rectangle bigger by one 1px on the bottom and right side, adjust for that.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean, how I said I'm new to this stuff, you could say I even know nothing of this.

Comment: He meant what he wrote. You can call it a bug or a quirk or a Pen property.. See [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-use-a-pen-to-draw-rectangles) for details..!

Answer (score 1):

The `Draw...` calls accepting a `Pen` instance seem (by default) to draw a rectangle bigger than 1 pixel to the right and bottom. So if you call something like `DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 0, 0, 100, 100)`, the rectangle on screen will look like as if it spans the coordinates 0, 0 to 101, 101.

The reasoning behind this is described here: [Pixel behaviour of FillRectangle and DrawRectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147569/pixel-behaviour-of-fillrectangle-and-drawrectangle)

To quickly fix your drawing, just pass coordinates smaller by 1 pixel to the right or bottom. E.g., to fix the above example, you'd call `DrawRectangle(0, 0, 99, 99)` to receive a rectangle spanning the coordinates 0, 0 to 100, 100 on the screen.

I personally resigned from using `Pens` and `Draw` calls for bordered rectangles and always use two `FillRectangle` calls (using `Brush` instances) as follows:

```
// Draws a white rectangle with black border
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, rect); // Draw border
rect.Inflate(-1, -1); // Decrease the size of the rectangle by 1 pixel on all sides
gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, rect); // Draw background above it
```

I have read that `FillRectangle` is faster than `DrawRectangle` (as it can simply bitblit the area, unlike `Draw` which requires to draw for separate lines with all possible shenanigans internally).