# DrawEllipse: Ellipse goes outside of the Bitmap size

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, bitmap, drawellipse

I want to draw a circle with `DrawEllipse` on a specified `Bitmap`, with the same size of the Bitmap, but the result is that the circle appears clipped at the edges.
Why this problem?

```
Bitmap layer = new Bitmap(80, 80);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(layer))
{
    using (Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black, 4))
    {
        g.DrawEllipse(p, new Rectangle(0, 0, layer.Width, layer.Height));
    }
}
pictureBox3.Size = new Size(100, 100);
pictureBox3.Image = layer;
```

[image: drawellipse result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default a Pen has a [PenAlignment.Center](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/z62ath7a(v=vs.110).aspx).

This means that half of its widh will draw outside the bounding rectangle.

You can simply avoid the issue by changing it to `PenAlignment.Inset`:

```
using (Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black, 4) { Alignment = PenAlignment.Inset})
{
    g.DrawEllipse(p, new Rectangle(0, 0, layer.Width, layer.Height));
}
```

[image]

**Update:** If you want to turn on smoothing for the Graphics object you will need 1 or 2 extra pixels on both sides of the pen stroke for the anti-aliasing pixels. Using a smaller bounding rectanlge can't be avoided now. But..:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, layer.Size);
rect.Inflate(-1, -1);  // or -2
```

..should do..

Comment: It works, but causes a problem with antialiasing mode: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50575461/3605220

Comment: That is true, antialiasing does take an extra pixel (on both sides of the pen stroke). No simple workaround that I know of, other than making the shape one pixel less high and wide. Which is less a drag than it sounds, considering the good old [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147569/pixel-behaviour-of-fillrectangle-and-drawrectangle) between e.g. DrawRectangle and FillRectangle..

Comment: I find that the `Inset` alignment of the `Pen` produces a result which is quite inferior than the `Center` alignment. I use this kind of reduction for the `Rectangle.Inflate()` method: `Rectangle.Inflate((int)(-(Pen.Width / 2) - 1), (int)(-(Pen.Width / 2)) - 1);` It works with both `SmoothingMode` set to `AntiAlias` and `HighQuality`. -1 is not need if there's no Antialiasing.